# How to open cps (current population survey data) in R

Tags: r, stata

I have a project using CPS data from the NBER, specifically Jan2016 cps file.  However, I am having a very difficult time trying to download it and read it into R or stata (I primarily use R). Downloading the data from the web comes as a zip file. I unzip it and it comes into a .dat file.  Reading the data in R produces, what looks like binary code (I know its not, but looks like it). Has anyone had to do this? Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the ipums-cps data from the Minnesota population center, you can download a stata file and read that directly into R